# Left-hand side of assignment must be a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, variables, boolean, method-call

I'm trying to call a boolean method in another class and Eclipse is reporting the above error on the second line in the following code:

```
CCR ccrFlags = new CCR();
if (ccrFlags.cBit() = set)
```

The method being called from the class called "CCR" is:

```
public boolean cBit() {
    boolean set = false;
    return set;
}
```

I imagine I'm probably going about this in an idiotic way and would be grateful for any advice. Thanks, Robert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparison should use `==` (double-equal):

```
CCR ccrFlags = new CCR();
if (ccrFlags.cBit() == set)
```

Answer (score 1):

in an if, the condition has to be always true or false.

your error is, that = only assigns the values, but it is not a logical operation which can be true or false.

So you have to use == in conditions.